# Using invalid option for select dropdown with Capybara and RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I'm trying to write a test that checks to see if an error was returned if a value sent with Capybara was invalid. The problem is, one of my form fields is a `<select>` field, and I want to ensure that an invalid input will result in a form error.

Problem is, I can only select the fields that are existing in the select box, all of which are "valid" according to my model's validation. I want to select an invalid field or somehow input some invalid data so that I can test for an error message.

How would I do this?

Comment: Do you have JavaScript available for your tests?

Comment: You can use JS to add a new option to your drop down. But ask yourself, what real world situation could cause the drop down to fail? What does the drop down hold options for? Say, for example, it was for a User to choose which Friend to remove. A real situation would be if said friend already removed the User, thus making removing the Friend erroneous. So to simulate that, you could select the Friend, then delete the friendship, then submit.

Comment: The situation would be that a malicious user tried to alter the value of an option. Now that I think about it, I think this would be better as a test of the model instead of an integration test, right?

Comment: @CalvinL: right, test the model validations

Comment: This works well enough for models. In my case, I want to ensure the user selects from a list they are allowed to select from, which brings in current_user, which puts this more in the controller logic.  In this case, it's a "filter results based on this field with this value" check, to ensure the value is in a per-user permitted list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution as mentioned in the comments -- test the model instead of doing it in an integration test. Thanks MrDanA and apneadiving!